# AutoUpdate images automatically in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba sub that inserts images into specific cells. The problem is
Application.ScreenUpdating = True does not work when you have different users using the workbook. When I have it on my pc it works fine but when its on some elses pc the images dont upload because its using the last known filepath. So if used by someone else they have to rerun it to produce the images on their pc.

```
Sub GetPic()
Dim fNameAndPath As String
Dim img As Object
Dim CommodityName1 As String, T1 As String
Dim myDir As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Worksheets("Picture").Activate
Dim shape As Excel.shape
Dim datarangeb As Range
Dim numberofcells As Integer
'Declare variable
    Dim strUserName As String
    'Get system logged in user name
    strUserName = Environ("Username")
    'Display the user name on sheet1
    

Set datarangeb = Sheets("Data").Range("b:b")

numberofcells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(datarangeb)
numberofcells = (numberofcells - 1) * 12 + 1

For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shape.Delete
Next


j = 7

For i = 2 To numberofcells

myDir = "C:\Users\" & strUserName & "\Villaron\SBP Admin Sales - Documents\Clients\00 - Estimating Register\rebar shapes" & "\"
CommodityName1 = Range("a" & i)


T1 = ".png"

fNameAndPath = myDir & CommodityName1 & T1





    Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
  
    With img
       'Move and Resize Image
       .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
       .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i).Left
       .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i).Top
       .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i & ":g" & i).Width
       .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i & ":g" & j).Height
       
       
          .Width = .Width - 10
       .Height = .Height - 5
       .Left = .Left + 5
       
errormessage:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
Exit Sub
MsgBox "File does not exist." & vbCrLf & "Check the name of the rebar!"
End If
       
    End With
    


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


i = i + 11
 j = j + 12
Next i


i = i - 1

Worksheets("Picture").Range("A" & i & ":i27000").Clear
Worksheets("Picture").Range("A" & i & ":i27000").ClearFormats
  
End Sub
```

Comment: In which pc the pictures are located?

Comment: Its the Onedrive folder. On my pc

Comment: Not sure I understand the situation, you run it in your pc and then send the file to another user pc and when it gets there the images are not there? please clarify